# How to pivot a table with time ranges into an array of ids for each date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that represents TOIs (time of interests). Each row contains the id of one TOI and the start and end date of the time range:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07 |
| C | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-07 |
| D | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-10 |
| E | 2021-01-07 | 2021-01-10 |
| F | 2021-01-07 | 2021-01-14 |

I would like to pivot the table, getting an array of ids for each cell. The expected result would be like this:

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A |
|  | B |
| 2021-01-02 | A |
|  | B |
| 2021-01-03 | B |
|  | C |
| 2021-01-04 | B |
|  | C |
|  | D |
| 2021-01-05 | B |
|  | C |
|  | D |
| 2021-01-06 | B |
|  | C |
|  | D |
| 2021-01-07 | B |
|  | C |
|  | D |
|  | E |
| 2021-01-08 | D |
|  | E |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-01-14 | F |

*In this example I am including the last day of the TOI.

Comment: . . It is not clear why `'B'` is repeated on `'2021-01-02'`.  I assume that is a typo.

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. Let me remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method generates the dates and then uses `join` and `aggregation` to bring in the data:

```
select dday, array_agg(t.id)
from (select min(start_date) as min_start_date,
             max(end_date) as max_end_date
      from t
     ) d cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(d.min_start_date, d.max_end_date, interval 1 day) dday left join
     t
     on dday between t.start_date and t.end_date
group by dday;
```

EDIT:

Actually a better way to write the query is:

```
select dday, array_agg(t.id)
from t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(t.start_date, t.end_date, interval 1 day)) dday 
group by dday;
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I got "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join" error.

Comment: @ramiroaznar . . . Actually, there is a better way to write the query that you want.  See the edit.  This should also be faster.

Comment: it worked! There is just a small typo in your last query. There is a missing bracket at the end (before `dday`).